# can i add more than 8 tabs on TabBarController?

Tags: iphone

Can I add more than 8 tabs on UITabBarController?

My code is here:

```
UITabbarController *tabbar=[[UITabbarController alloc]init];
tabbar addTabItems......
```

Comment: yes you can add more than 8 tabs...

Answer (score 2):

You can add as many view controllers to `UITabBarController` as you want. The right most tab button will be called `More` with three dots which will take you to the screen where you can edit which view controllers to show and which ones to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add 8 tabbars but only 5 will be visible and for remaining, it'll show you a dotted tab on clicking that tab it'll show the list of remaining tabs in your tabbar.

Comment: Actually I want to add 8 Tabbars and dont want tableview for more tabs ,so can any one please help me.

Comment: Create default UITabbar application it will help you out.